# cannot draw shape in canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a canvas in xaml defined as following. However adding a rectangle in it doesn't show any thing.

```
<lib:DrawingCanvas x:Name="drawingCanvas" Background="White" AllowDrop="True">
    <Rectangle Margin="20,20,20,20"  Fill="Black" Stroke="White" Width="100" Height="100">
    </Rectangle>
</lib:DrawingCanvas>
```

Can you give me some hints here?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your DrawingCanvas based on?

Comment: Can you post the code of `lib:DrawingCanvas`?

Comment: DrawingCanvas is derived from Canvas class so it has its attributes. My problem is that I don't know how to drag and drop a simple shape on it.  I have created a toolbar where it hold a rectangle. Now, I want to drag it and show it on canvas. Please kindly advise.

Comment: This is the C# 'code'  public class DrawingCanvas : Canvas 'code' and in the xaml file I have             <lib:DrawingCanvas x:Name="drawingCanvas" Background="White" AllowDrop="True" DragDrop.Drop="drawingCanvas_Drop">
</lib:DrawingCanvas>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using a Canvas, you're using a "DrawingCanvas", so I can't speak for any differences.  But assuming it derives from Canvas:

You need to set the attached properties for the Rectangle.  These are *Canvas.Left **or** Canvas.Right*, in addition to *Canvas.Top **or** Canvas.Bottom*.

For example:

```
<Rectangle Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="100" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Black" />
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Yes, it its code it is derived from Canvas. However, I'm new to WPF ... are you saying that I have to use DependencyProperty and register() function to add a rectangle?

Comment: oh I see. I did add Canvase.Left and right but it doesn't show up. maybe I have to do more try/error position.